# How to call on methods held inside an array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, instantiation

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        shape[] myShapes = new shape[3];
        myShapes[0] = new cube(3);
        myShapes[1] = new Sphere(2);
        myShapes[2] = new Cylinder(3, 4);
        
        for (shape: myShapes)
            System.out.println()
    }
}

class cube extends shape {

    public double side;
    public double newSide;
    public double volume;
    public double surface;

    public cube(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public void cubeVolume(){
        volume = Math.pow(side,3);
        System.out.println (volume);
    }

    public void cubeSurface(){
        surface = Math.pow(side,2) * 6;
        System.out.println (surface);
    }


}

abstract class shape{
    protected double volume;
    protected double surface;

}

public class Sphere extends shape {

    public double radius;
    public double volume;
    public double area;
    public double i = 4;
    public double j = 3;

    public Sphere(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void sphereVolume(){
        volume = i/j * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,3);
        System.out.println(volume);
    }

    public void surfaceArea(){
        area = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2);
        System.out.println(area);

    }

}

public class Cylinder extends shape{

    public double radius;
    public double height;
    public double cylinderVolume;
    public double cylinderArea;

    public Cylinder(double radius, double height) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void surface(){
        cylinderArea = 2 * Math.PI * radius * height;
        System.out.println(cylinderArea);
    }

    public void volume(){
        cylinderVolume = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) * height;
        System.out.println(cylinderVolume);
    }

}
```

I do not think the title encompasses my question well. I am instantiating a new object and storing that object within the array myShapes. The class for each object has a method to calculate the surface area and volume. I need to call on all these methods, and I believe this can be done with a for loop, but I am not sure how. I am completely stumped.

Comment: It would help us to see your class hierarchy. What is the Cube, Sphere, Cylinder, and Shape objects? If the surface area and volume methods is declared in the Shape object, then it should work.

Comment: Does your base class `shape` declare those methods that you want to call?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the other classes. The shape class is abstract and declares the variables volume and area.

Comment: It greatly helps readability if you follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), especially classes should be `SentenceCase` and variables/parameters `camelCase`.

Answer (score 1):

Add abstract methods to your superclass:

```
abstract class Shape {
    // Note: No fields
    public abstract double surfaceArea();
    public abstract double volume();
}
```

Implement them in your subclasses, eg for `Cylinder`:

```
public class Cylinder extends Shape {
    // radius and height fields and constructor not shown

    public double surfaceArea() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius * height;
    }

    public double volume() {
        return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) * height;
    }
}
```

Then print them in your loop:

```
for (shape : myShapes) {
    System.out.println("Surface area = " + shape.surfaceArea + ", volume = " + shape.volume());
}
```

Note that you don't want to print inside the methods - that's a rendering issue and should be done by the caller if appropriate. For example, you wouldn't want lots of output if you were just doing calculations and comparisons of shapes.

Also, it greatly helps readability if you follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), especially classes should be `SentenceCase` and variables/parameters `camelCase`, so call your classes `Shape` instead of `shape`, `Cube` instead of `cube` etc.

If you don't have common fields, prefer an `interface` over an `abstract class` for the supertype.

Comment: Ok, now I get this error: cube is not abstract and does not override abstract method surface() in shape class cube extends shape. This is why I didn't include abstract methods to begin with. I do not understand why it is fussing over the cube class not being abstract. I thought that was the whole point around abstract methods is to override them through child methods that are not abstract.

Comment: @Noobprogrammer Yes, and then your concrete classes need to provide implementations of the methods declared abstract in the base class.

Comment: @Noobprogrammer make sure your method names in your subclasses exactly match those of the superclass

Answer (score 0):

If your storing your objects inside a `shape[]` array then, you need to make sure to define
`volume()` & `surfaceArea()` as abstract methods in your `shape class` so, that each of your shapes (Cylinder, Sphere, etc.) will then be able to override and implement. They need to be named the same as well.